# Configuring Apache for Yii2 UrlManager's 'enablePrettyUrl' parametre on Windows

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server, yii2

I've tryed to follow [Yii2 Official Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#recommended-apache-configuration) to configure Apache-2.4x64 for enablePrettyUrl option. My issue is that I've got 500 Server Error when trying to access *localhost/about/web/* in my browser. I've placed **.htaccess** in my **about/web** folder.
Here's it's configuration:

```
# Set document root to be "basic/web"
DocumentRoot "d:/openserver/domains/localhost/about/web"

<Directory "d:/openserver/domains/localhost/about/web">
    # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
    RewriteEngine on
    # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . index.php

    # ...other settings...
</Directory>
```

Maybe something wrong with path to about/web? I have this error only on my Windows machine.

Comment: What is in Apache logs?

Comment: path/to/localhost/about/web/.htaccess: DocumentRoot not allowed here, referer: http://dev/about/

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the logs. Now I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Directory` and `DocumentRoot` are not allowed in the .htaccess file, they should be in the apache configuration (or in your VirtualHost config file).

In your case, the .htaccess file is being read, that is why it gives youa error 500 (the file is read but it containt systax errors or bad commands). Therefore, it should be enough to remove the 'Directory`and`DocumentRoot` commands and leave the file just with:

```
# use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Please, make sure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled in your apache installation.

Comment: Then should I do the same in _httpd.conf_?

Comment: Just remove the `Directory` and `DocumentRoot` commands from the .htaccess file